# SQL Server paging query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

Urggggg! I've been struggling with this for a long time! I can do it with MySQL so easy but not with SQL Server :(

Here are the simplified tables which should be joined all together.

[image]

Combining all of them by using inner join syntax, I have to write a query to use for paging in the future (btw, PHP). Let's say I need all ID, Name, and Date info which a picture is taken between 2012-10-01 and 2012-10-30.... and 20 people per page.

What would be the easiest query to achieve the goal here? (I tried NOT IN.. but it was so buggy cuz I'm not used to 'NOT IN' stuff...)

You can ignore the performance speed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it in SQL Server 2005+:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Photo, CreatedDate, rowNum, (rowNum / 20) + 1 as pageNum
FROM (
    SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.Photo, c.Created_Date
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY c.Created_Date ASC) as rowNum
    FROM a
       JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
       JOIN c ON c.photo = b.photo
    WHERE c.Created_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-1' AND '2012-10-30'
) x
WHERE (rowNum / 20) + 1 = 1
```

Note that I'm using a little integer division trickery to calculate page number.

Since pre-2005 sadly doesn't have row_number(), I'd use an intermediate table with an identity column:

```
    SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.Photo, c.Created_Date
       , identity(int,1,1) as rowNum
    INTO t
    FROM a
       JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
       JOIN c ON c.photo = b.photo
    WHERE c.Created_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-1' AND '2012-10-30'
    ORDER BY c.Created_Date ASC
    GO

    ALTER TABLE t ADD pageNum AS rowNum / 20
    GO

    SELECT ID, Name, Photo, Created_Date, rowNum
    FROM t
    WHERE pageNum = 1
```

Comment: What I meant by 'paging' is.. you're getting partial # of information out of the total.  Stackoverflow itself is a good example. If you search something, it doesn't display the entire result but only some for the first page. If you go to the next page, you get another small bunch of info and so on. This is what should be done here.

Comment: Looks quite good except for Row_Number() is not supported :'(

Comment: bummer...that's right, I think Row_Number() is new in 2008. that's just a shortcut for a slower version using a temporary table and an identity column - will edit shortly...

Comment: Row_Number was introduced in 2005, if you really design an application in 2013 based on SQL 2000... check if its an option for you to use the free Express Editons of newer Microsoft SQL Server versions.

Comment: Is this good to performance? `select 20 from (select 100000)` everytime you will make a query that will fetch all, and subselect them.

Comment: Aagh. I'm starting to realise what @Raccoon might have meant by "MS Server 2003". Do you mean *MS Access 2003* ??

Comment: i do not understand this trick WHERE (rowNum / 20) + 1 = 1 ?? if i want to fetch 1 to 20 records then??

Comment: the trick is: WHERE (rowNum / [size of each page]) + 1 = [page you want to retrieve]. So if you want your page to be 10 items long and you want page number 7 (rows 61-70), you would do: WHERE (rowNum / 10) + 1 = 7

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I did it a long time ago..

```
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT TOP y * FROM (
           SELECT TOP x * FROM sometable
           ORDER BY somefield ASC
      )
      ORDER BY somefield DESC)
ORDER BY somefield
```

> The innermost query, SELECT TOP x, grabs the first x number of rows,
>   the second query SELECT TOP y, gets the last y of x rows, and the
>   outermost query, SELECT * puts the results in the right order.

Here is a blog post that explains how it works Here is a blog article I wrote back in 2006 talking about it http://code.rawlinson.us/2006/12/t-sql-query-paging.html

The tl;dr; of the post is from this paragraph:

> For example, let’s say we want the first page, so the top 20 results. That is pretty easy, just use SELECT TOP 20 …. but what about the second or subsequent pages? How do you get the 21-40 items? It’s easier than you might suspect. What you are actually trying to get is the bottom y of the top x results. To look at that another way you want the top y of the top x results ordered backwards.

It's up to you how you calculate and provide the x and y values to the query.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft added native paging features in SQL Server 2012 and above using ["OFFSET" and "FETCH"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx#Offset).  You can use this feature as below:

```
-- Skip the first 500 rows and return the next 100
SELECT *
FROM TableName
ORDER BY [ID]
    OFFSET 500 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

For the `OFFSET __` and `FETCH NEXT __` clauses, you can specify constant values (as above), or you can specify variables, expressions, or constant scalar subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with Sql Server 2008 + [AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587) database

```
DECLARE @PageIndex INT, @RowsPerPage INT
DECLARE @StartRow INT, @EndRow INT;

SET @PageIndex = 1;
SET @RowsPerPage = 500;
SET @StartRow = ((@PageIndex - 1) * @RowsPerPage) + 1;
SET @EndRow = @StartRow + @RowsPerPage - 1;

--append#1
WITH PAGE_ROWS
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, SalesOrderNumber ASC) AS ROW_NO
    , COUNT(*) OVER() AS TOTAL_ROWS
    , *
FROM( 
    --working query
    SELECT S.SalesOrderID
        , S.SalesOrderNumber
        , S.OrderDate
        , S.DueDate
        , S.ShipDate
        , S.Status
        , S.PurchaseOrderNumber
        , C.AccountNumber
        , P.FirstName, P.MiddleName, P.LastName
    FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS S
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Sales].[Customer] AS C ON C.CustomerID=S.CustomerID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Person].[Person] AS P ON P.BusinessEntityID=C.PersonID
--append#2
) AS Src)
SELECT CEILING(TOTAL_ROWS/ CAST(@RowsPerPage AS DECIMAL(20,2))) AS TOTAL_PAGES
    ,*
FROM PAGE_ROWS
WHERE ROW_NO BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, SalesOrderNumber ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER  Proc [dbo].[Sp_PagingonTable] 
@SearchText varchar(255) = null,
@ChannelName varchar(255)= null,
@ChannelCategory varchar(255)= null,
@ChannelType varchar(255)= null,
@PageNo int,
@PageSize int,
@TotalPages int output
As
DECLARE  @VariableTable TABLE
(
Rownumber INT,
ReferralHierarchyKey BIGINT, 
ReferralID VARCHAR(255), 
ChannelDetail VARCHAR(255),     
ChannelName VARCHAR(255),
ChannelCategory VARCHAR(255),
ChannelType VARCHAR(255)
)
 /*---Inserting Data into variable Table-------------*/
INSERT INTO @VariableTable
SELECT   
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ColumnID) as Rownumber,*
 FROM [dbo].[TableName]
 WHERE (@SearchText IS NULL OR ChannelDetail LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%')                                 And       (@ChannelName  IS NULL OR ChannelName  = @ChannelName )
/*--Applying Paging on filter Table--*/
SELECT 
        ReferralID
       ,ChannelDetail
       ,ChannelName
       ,ChannelCategory
       ,ChannelType 
    FROM 
        @VariableTable
WHERE Rownumber between (((@PageNo -1) *@PageSize)+1) and @PageNo *    @PageSize
 /*--Getting Total Pages After filter Table---*/
 SELECT @TotalPages =  (Count(*) + @PageSize - 1)/@PageSize FROM  @VariableTable
 SELECT @TotalPages
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked Taha Siddiqui's answer except that it requires modifying the passed in query and it didn't work for an SQL UNION statement that I have to use due to some very poor design decisions made by a former co-worker.

The generic SQL Server query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by ID) as row_num, * FROM (
      <<Put Your Query Here>>
    ) AS tempTable1
) AS tempTable2 WHERE row_num >= ((pageNum -1) * pageSize) AND row_num < ((pageNum -1) * pageSize) + pageSize;
```

I created a Java function that assumes one-based paging:

```
    public static String buildPagingQuery(String sqlStr, String sortExpression, int pageNum, int pageSize) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(sortExpression)) { //NOTE: uses org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
            sortExpression = " (select 0)";
        }

        int startIndex = ((pageNum - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
        int endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("SELECT * FROM (");
        sb.append("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ");
        sb.append(sortExpression);
        sb.append(") as row_num, * FROM (");
        sb.append(sqlStr);
        sb.append(") as tempTable1 ");
        sb.append(") AS tempTable2  "); 
        sb.append("WHERE row_num >= ").append(startIndex);
        sb.append(" AND row_num < ").append(endIndex);

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I have not yet checked performance on a large table.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the same by CTE (Common Table Expressions).First we need to set current page number and offset of the result from which we need to fetch.Then we have to order the result set by ROW_NUMBER.and store the result by using cte feature.then filter the result with page size and offset against Row number.
The SQL query is as follows

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT=1 ,@PageNumber INT=2

DECLARE @Offset int =(@PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1))+1

;WITH Results_CTE AS
(

    SELECT *,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FieldName) AS RowNum
    FROM TABLENAME
  )  

  SELECT *
  FROM Results_CTE
  WHERE RowNum>=@Offset AND RowNum < @Offset + @PageSize

END
```

https://amonghorizon.blogspot.com/2020/07/sql-server-query-for-pagination-control.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods from the following class

```
internal class PagingHelper
{
    public static String ParseQueryForPagingAndSorting(String strSQL, string SortExpression, int StartIndex, int EndIndex)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortExpression))
            SortExpression = " (select 0)";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("select * from (");
        sb.Append(" select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY " + SortExpression + ") AS row_num,");
        int index = strSQL.ToLower().IndexOf('t', 0);
        sb.Append(strSQL.Substring(index + 2));
        sb.Append(")");
        sb.Append(" AS TempTable");
        sb.Append(" where row_num>=" + StartIndex.ToString() + " AND row_num<=" + EndIndex.ToString());
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static String ParseQueryForCount(String strSQL)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("select count(*) from");
        sb.Append("(");
        sb.Append(strSQL);
        sb.Append(")");
        sb.Append(" AS TempTable");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a another way I have found to do this into Sql server 2012

http://raresql.com/2012/07/01/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-using-order-by-offset-and-fetch-next/