# SQL query with limit

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
ID   | videoid  | title
=========================
1    | id1      | title1
2    | id2      | title2
3    | id3      | title3
```

And I want to create select method that search in the title row with:

```
SELECT * FROM [movie].[dbo].[movies] 
WHERE title like '%' + '%s' + '%'
```

And I'm looking for something like Limit in MySQL that from the `SELECT` results I will be able to get the `0-20,21-40,41-60` results.

Any help with this query?

I tried to use `LIMIT 0, 10` and I received this error:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'LIMIT'.
```

Comment: Also, you've got one too many '%', I think.

Comment: What is your goal with this sql and where are you planning to use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server paging query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421761/sql-server-paging-query)

Comment: @RaimondKuipers I want to build `webservice` that get search string and return results from the sql database. but i want to return every time 20 results and not all the results.

Comment: @MTA, are you going to return 20 results every time or you want to returned result based on paging like `0-20` for the first call, then `20-40` for the second ?

Comment: @Habib yes this is what i want to achieve

Comment: @MTA, yes ??? what just 20 records irrespective of paging or you need paging ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `TOP N` with SQL SERVER.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [movie].[dbo].[movies] 
WHERE title like '%' + '%s' + '%'
ORDER BY SomeColumn -- Specify your column for ordering
```

See: [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

> Limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number
>   of rows or percentage of rows in SQL Server

Also look under [Best Practices in docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

> In a SELECT statement, always use an ORDER BY clause with the TOP
>   clause. This is the only way to predictably indicate which rows are
>   affected by TOP.

If you are looking for Paging records then you will need [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Yes for paging [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) should be used.

Comment: TOP has no meaning without ORDER BY.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, Are you sure about it ? Because I think SELECT just returns records in undetermined order , is it because of the TOP keyword that the returned results would be in order based on PK ?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar [example 1](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(1).sql), [example 2](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(2).sql), [example 3](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(3).sql)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, I believe `gvee` is right, Here it is in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) `In a SELECT statement, always use an ORDER BY clause with the TOP clause. This is the only way to predictably indicate which rows are affected by TOP.`

Comment: @gvee Well, then I stand corrected. I usually use `ORDER BY`, but I guess I was comforted by the fact that SQL Management Studio almost always order by the PK :-) Sorry to interrupt. Keep going...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar "almost always" <> "always" ;)

Comment: Two downvotes, hmmm something must be horribly wrong.

Comment: @gvee, that is why I mentioned it under best practices, but I think you are right I should add it to the actual statement as well.

Comment: @gvee That is true, but in some cases (as in one of our customer's database) I just need to get the first value from a set of rows, as it is equal for all rows, so there I don't need an `ORDER BY`. One could rightfully argue that the data model is a WTF in itself, but that's not the topic here :-D

Answer (score 3):

There's no equivalent in T-SQL. `TOP` allows you to get only the first `x` results from the result set. You can use a trick. Using `ROW_NUMBER` you can add a new column that starts from 1 and is incremented automatically.

Like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER (SomeExpression), Field FROM ...
```

Then you can use

```
SELECT TOP x FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, ID, videoid, title FROM ...
) tmp
WHERE RowNumber > Y ORDER BY RowNumber ASC
```

The trick is that this numbering is independent of the other fields, so using the same filter you'll always get the same `RowNumber`s  and thus can filter *again*. This mimicks what `LIMIT` does.

For example, to get the entries 1 - 9 entries, you'd write:

```
SELECT TOP 9 FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, ID, videoid, title FROM ...
) tmp
WHERE RowNumber >= 1 ORDER BY RowNumber ASC
```

Next Page:

```
SELECT TOP 9 FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, ID, videoid, title FROM ...
) tmp
WHERE RowNumber >= 10 ORDER BY RowNumber ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

In **SQL Server 2012** a new feature was introduced that provides this functionality.

Look at the OFFSET part of [the ORDER BY clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
ORDER
    BY some_column
       OFFSET 20 ROWS
       FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

This will return the results 20-30 of your resultset (ordered by `some_column`)

For **SQL Server 2005 - 2008R2** you can use windowed functions to perform the same action:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT *
             , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY some_column) As sequence
        FROM   your_table
       ) As a_subquery
WHERE  sequence >= 20
AND    sequence <= 30
```

For versions of SQL Server **prior to SQL Server 2005** there is no efficient way of achieving this effect. Here's something that does the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT *
             , (
                SELECT Count(*)
                FROM   your_table As x
                WHERE  x.some_column <= your_table.some_column
               ) As sequence
        FROM   your_table
       ) As a_subquery
WHERE  sequence >= 20
AND    sequence <= 30
```

**Final notes:** for your results to be [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) `some_column` should be unique. If it isn't then you need to add extra column(s) in to the equation to provide a deterministic sort order for your sequence.

Also note that `SELECT * ...` should be avoided in all production code. Don't be lazy [like I was in this answer `;-)`] - list out *only* the columns required.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Top`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [movie].[dbo].[movies] 
WHERE title like '%' + '%s' + '%'
```

When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order.

Read more [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

To get results like 10-20, use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM 
 (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (id_field) as SlNo, ID, videoid, title 
  FROM TableName) T
WHERE SlNo>=10
ORDER BY id_field
```

Comment: This doesn't work exactly as `LIMIT` in that you can't get results 10 - 20.

Comment: TOP has no meaning without ORDER BY. [example 1](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(1).sql), [example 2](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(2).sql), [example 3](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(3).sql)

Answer (score 1):

I dont't think there's `LIMIT` in SQL server. Use `TOP` instead. `TOP` returns the first N rows of a query, so if it's `TOP 10`, even if you have a thousand rows, it will only return the first 10. Try this...

```
SELECT TOP 60 * 
FROM [movie].[dbo].[movies] 
WHERE title like '%' + '%s' + '%'
```

Comment: This does not allow for paging as `LIMIT`, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method for this purpose:

Method 1: **ORDER BY**

```
SELECT * 
FROM [movie].[dbo].[movies] 
WHERE title like '%' + '%s' + '%'
ORDER BY ID OFFSET 21 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Method 2: **ROW_NUMBER**

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY ID)row
        FROM [movie].[dbo].[movies]
        WHERE title like '%' + '%s' + '%'
    )z
WHERE row>20
    AND row<=40
```

Method 3: **Top N**

```
SELECT TOP 20 *
FROM (  SELECT TOP 40 *
        FROM [movie].[dbo].[movies] 
        WHERE title like '%' + '%s' + '%'
        ORDER BY ID
    )z
ORDER BY ID DESC
```